# Kann der Ausdruck "mehr als ...." nur adverbial verwendet werden?

Tags: phrase

> Ich bin der Überzeugung, mehr als geeignet für diese Stelle zu sein.
>   Ich bin der Überzeugung, ein mehr als geeigneter Bewerber zu sein.

Ist der zweite Satz möglich? Und wenn ja, wie kann ich das besser zum Ausdruck bringen?

Comment: Beide Sätze sind richtig. Der zweite Satz muss auch nicht verbessert werden, das ist bereits die kürzeste Form, diesen Gedanken auszudrücken.

Comment: @Janka Warum machst du aus deinem Kommentar nicht eine Antwort? Dem Kommentar ist ja nichts mehr hinzuzufügen...

Comment: Doch, kürzer wäre `Ich bin überzeugt, ein mehr als geeigneter Bewerber zu sein.` Vorsicht jedoch dann mit `Ich bin mehr als überzeugt, ein geeigneter Bewerber zu sein.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beide Sätze sind richtig (wie @Janka bereits in dem Kommentar zur Frage schreibt).

In beiden Sätzen wird "mehr als" adverbial verwendet, als Modifikation des Adjektivs "geeignet". Im ersten Satz handelt es sich bei "geeignet" um ein prädikatives Adjektiv, im zweiten bei "geeigneter" um ein "ganz normales" Adjektiv.